# Calculating object velocity at perihelion

Tags: orbit, velocity

I would like to calculate the velocity of an asteroid orbiting around a star (Sun) at the perihelion of its orbit. I know the excentricity of the ellipse and its semimajor axis.

I have found that the vis-viva equation is used to calculate the velocity of an object on an elliptical orbit and that the perihelion is at distance r = a(1-e). However I (simply enough) cannot see how to mathematically combine these two pieces of information in order to get the velocity at the perihelion.

(I am not so much looking for just a formula but rather a proof/intuition regarding how to get from the vis-visa equation for velocity to a perihelion velocity equation)

Comment: Generally, it is impossible without knowing the mass of the star. If you know that, just substitute r for (1-e)a in the formula ... after you do that, you'll notice that you know all parameters of the equation and can calculate the speed.

Comment: @Tosic i kinda feel a little dumb now tbh haha, I know the mass of the star, I had everything this whole time... If you put that as an answer I'll accept it !

Comment: No problem. There is no shame in asking, but in refusing to learn :-)

Comment: BTW, when doing calculations involving GM it's more accurate to use the [standard gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) than to use separate values of G & M.

Comment: @PM2Ring alright, glad to gain some knowledge ! Just a question though: how can the sgp be known to a greater accuracy than GM ? (I'm guessing it has to do with how it's calculated but...)

Comment: @A.D That Wikipedia article briefly explains: *"Conversely, measurements of the smaller body's orbit only provide information on the product, μ, not G and M separately."* Also see https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39930 It's *really* hard to measure G to high precision. It's generally done using some variation of the [Cavendish torsion balance experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment). Also see [Bending Spacetime in the Basement](https://www.fourmilab.ch/gravitation/foobar/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vis-viva equation is commonly written like this:

$$v^2 = GM\left(\frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a}\right)$$.

For $r=a(1-e)$:

$$v = \sqrt{GM\left(\frac{2}{a(1-e)} - \frac{1}{a}\right)} = \sqrt{GM\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{2}{1-e}-1\right)} = \sqrt{GM\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{1+e}{1-e}\right)}$$.

The derivation of the vis-viva equation is not at all trivial and can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation).

The product $GM$ is also called the [standard gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) and for solar system bodies is often known more accurately than $G$ and $M$ separately. For the Sun $GM_☉$ is about 1.327E+20 m³ s⁻² which in different units is 1.327E+11 km³ s⁻² or about 1.0 AU³ year⁻².

Comment: In units of years & AU, $GM_\odot$ is $4\pi^2$, so Earth's mean speed is $2\pi$ AU/year.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this without having to know or derive the vis-viva equation, just by applying conservation of energy and angular momentum.

At perihelion and aphelion the velocities are purely tangential, so conservation of angular momentum yields
$$ r_p v_p = r_a v_a\ ,$$
$$ a(1-e)v_p = a(1+e)v_a\ .$$
Conservation of energy (potential plus kinetic) then gives
$$ -\frac{GM}{r_p} + \frac{v_p^{2}}{2} = -\frac{GM}{r_a} + \frac{v_a^2}{2}\ , $$
$$ -\frac{GM}{a(1-e)} + \frac{v_p^{2}}{2} = -\frac{GM}{a(1+e)} + \frac{v_a^2}{2}\ . $$
Eliminating $v_a$ gives
$$ v_p = \left( \frac{GM}{a}\frac{(1+e)}{(1-e)}\right)^{1/2}\ . $$

Comment: *Beautiful!* :-)

Comment: This helped me a lot too!